# JSQMessageViewController crashed to open

Tags: swift, crash, xcode8, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

I am trying to implement a chat with JSQMessage framework.
But when i run it, the application crash and i have this error:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

and open code on

> class AppDelegate: .......... <- Thread1: signal SIGABRT

I am using xcode 8.2 and JSQMessageViewController ver. 7.3.4

This my code:

```
import UIKit
import JSQMessagesViewController

class ChatViewController: JSQMessagesViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

  }


@IBAction func back(_ sender: Any) {
    navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
  }     
 }
```

How can I fix this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: There should be more error data above that message of type NSexception. Adding that to your question will help get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Oftentimes learning a library or framework is the fastest when looking at an example. The file you are looking for can be found [here](https://github.com/jessesquires/JSQMessagesViewController/blob/develop/SwiftExample/SwiftExample/ChatViewController.swift). Also the entire encapsulating example Xcodeworkspace will help teach you.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [Minimal-JSQMessagesViewController-Using-Swift-3](https://macmedan.github.io/jekyll/update/2016/11/20/Minimal-JSQMessagesViewController-Using-Swift-3.html) it is the least you need to get up and going.

Hope that helps

Comment: The issue is fixed.
I have to set: `self.senderId` and `self.senderDisplayName`
so it works.
Thank all for help.